# Selective read of pandas dataframe containing mixed type columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, hdf5, hdf

I have pandas tables with column containing varibale length lists with thousands of rows, for example,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({0: [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]}, )

###Output: 
df
                0
0          [1, 2]
1       [3, 4, 5]
2             [7]
3  [8, 9, 10, 11]
```

I can store the file in the drive by using

```
with pd.HDFStore('out_file', mode='w') as store:
      df.to_hdf(store, key='data1')
```

but not using following because type of column is `object`.

```
with pd.HDFStore('out_file', mode='w') as store:
      df.to_hdf(store, key='data1', format='table', data_columns=True)
```

How can I read few indexes from the file instead of reading the complete file and then droping undesired rows? If hdf5 can not handle queries for this type of dataframe, then what are the alterantives data formats. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround I found is store the data as `str` strings in order to read only selective rows,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({0: [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]}, )

# Write
with pd.HDFStore('out_file', mode='w') as store:
      df.astype(str).to_hdf(store, key='data1', format='table', data_columns=True)

# Now Read some rows
d.read_hdf('out_file', key='data1', where='index >1 & index < 2')
```